# On the proof of Homotopy lifting property for fiber bundles

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It's well known that a fiber bundle has homotopy lifting property (HLP) for all spaces:

Let $p:E\to B$ be a locally trivial fiber bundle. Let $X$ be a topological space.  Suppose $\tilde{f}: X\to E$ is a lift of $f:X\to B$ and there is a homotopy $f_t:X\times I \to B$ with $f_0(x)=f(x)$. Then there is a map $\tilde{f}_t:X\times I \to E$, which is a lift of $f_t$ and $\tilde{f}_0=\tilde{f}$.

In Allen Hatcher's book, he gives a proof for the case $X=I^n$:

First divide $I^n$ into small cubes $C$ and $I$ into intervals $I_j=[t_j,t_{j+1}]$ so that each $f(C\times I_j)\subset B$ is contained in a nbh which adimits a trivialization. Assume by induction on $n$ that $\tilde{f}_t$ has already been constructed over $\partial C$ for each of the subcubes $C$. Then extend this $\tilde{f}_t$ over a cube $C$.

**My question is: Why do we first construct $\tilde{f}_t$ on $\partial C$?  Can we construct in the following way**:

For any point $x\in X$, there is a nbh $U_{f(x)}$ of $f(x)$ with trivialization 
$$
h: p^{-1}(U_{f(x)})\to U_{f(x)} \times F. 
$$
Then there is a nbh $U_x$ and interval $I_x=[0,t_0]$ such that  $f(U_x\times I_x)\subset U_{f(x)}$. Suppose 
$$
h(\tilde{f}(x))=(f(x),z)
$$ 
with $z\in F$.  For $t\in [0,t_0]$, $\tilde{f}_t(x)$ is defined to be the point satisfying
 $$
 h(\tilde{f}_t(x))=(f_t(x),z).
 $$
 Then we consider $(x,t_0)$ instead of $(x,0)$. We finally can define $\tilde{f}(x,t)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Have you checked that $\overline f$ is continuous?